# Display data in response in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, response

I want to display additional variable called availableSpots in the response which is not defined in the schema:

The response:

```
[
    {
        "contactInfo": {
            "name": "Claudia Shields",
            "phoneNumber": 8904672101
        },
        "coordinates": {
            "lng": 34.048954,
            "lat": 10.299556
        },
        "_id": "62e11ab3079daa939290fa07",
        "about": "Nisi occaecat ipsum",
        "parkingImage": [],
        "location": [
            {
                something
            }
        ],
        "price": 5,
        "availability": [
            {
                "day": "Saturday",
                "startTime": "09:00",
                "endTime": "14:00",
                "_id": "62e11ab3079daa939290fa09"
            },...
        ],
        "parkingType": "residence",
        "parkingInfo": [
            {
                "parkingName": "Fountain Avenue",
                "default": []
            }
        ],
        "totalSpots": 127,
        "status": "active",
        "isFeePaid": false,
        "parkingZone": [],
        "specialEvents": []
    }
]
```

The GET route which is sending above response :

```
exports.getParkingListByCriteria = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    endTime = getEndTime(req.body.startTime, req.body.duration);
    let parkings = await Parking.find(
      {
        "location.city": req.body.city,
      }
    )
    let parkingList = [];
    let parkingIds = [];
    parkings.forEach((parking) => {
      isParkingAvailable(parking.availability, req.body.startTime, endTime);
      {
        parkingList.push(parking);
        parkingIds.push(parking._id);
      }
    });
    const bookings = await Booking.find({
      "isBookingCancelled.value": false,
      parkingId: { $in: parkingIds },
    });

    let groupBookings = {};
    let tmppid = "";
    bookings.forEach((booking) => {
      tmppid = booking.parkingId.toString();
      if (typeof groupBookings[tmppid] === "undefined")
        groupBookings[tmppid] = [];
      groupBookings[tmppid].push(booking);
    });
    parkingList = parkingList.filter((booking) => {
      const booked = groupBookings[booking._id];
      const alreadyBooked = booked ? booked.length : 0;
      availableSpots = booking.totalSpots - alreadyBooked; //Here it is defined BUT in a function so Unable to access it outside of a function
      console.log("available spots -> ", availableSpots);
      return booking.totalSpots > alreadyBooked;
    });

    res.status(200).send(parkingList);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

The available spots is basically a total parking spots - already booked spots.
It is displaying it in the console but how to display as a response?

Answer (score 0):

```
parkingList = parkingList.map((booking) => {
  const booked = groupBookings[booking._id]
  const alreadyBooked = booked ? booked.length : 0
  availableSpots = booking.totalSpots - alreadyBooked
  return {...booking, availableSpots, booked, alreadyBooked}
})
.filter((booking) => booking.totalSpots > booking.alreadyBooked )
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I found another solution.

Comment: Can you please show me the code how to display the available spots only for the requested day. The above example is for all days. It finds all the bookings for that parking regardless of the day

Comment: let parkings = await Parking.find(
    {
        $and: [
            {'location.city': req.body.city},
            {availability: {$elemMatch: {day:'Saturday'}}}
        ]
    }
)